# Google Apps Script and Source Code Tools for version control?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

This question is an addition to the topic [Should Google App Scripts be stored in version control like GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712593/should-google-app-scripts-be-stored-in-version-control-like-github)

Is there any possibility that source code versioning for Google Apps Script Projects is (or will be) covered by the still Beta "Source Code Tools" (https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/source-tools)

From documentation of the Cloud Repositories (cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/) I see: 
"Each project you create in the Google Developers Console has an associated Cloud Source Repository. ",

while in the documentation for Google Application Script project (developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) I see: "Every Apps Script project automatically creates its own project in the Google Developers Console to control authorization." (only authorization, but maybe also source code versioning?)

From what I tested so far it seems that sources of Google App Script projects are not covered by the Versioning System.

Thank you,
Ado

Answer (score 1):

There is one project out there that does a pretty solid job with github.  What makes it special is that is has some trickery to be able to import and export your project with the associated libraries and Advanced services.

https://github.com/brucemcpherson/gasGit

As for official support the best people can do is star the issues in your linked question.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote this chrome extension to make it easy to sync your code between GAS and Github.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo

This will work on the GAS IDE, simply sync your code between GAS and Github Repo/Gist with the familiar pull/push.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: The question is asking for a tool but not "how can I manage the gas code with version control?" and I just post a tool as an answer, I don't think there's something wrong.